# Open a file in C - Why isn't it loading all the matrix or deleting \n?

Tags: c

I'm tring to build a simple program where i say the dimensions of a matrix i want, and i read that size from a txt file to a 2D array.

So i have the following letters as it is, in a txt file called soup.txt

```
ORCA
RAIO
ATNS
```

I want this 3x4 matrix to be loaded to an array. This are the structs and the functions that i have:

```
typedef struct dicionario{
char matrix[200][200];
}*DICIONARIO;

//Function to load the matrix
void abresopa(FILE *fs, char *s,DICIONARIO sopa,int dimy,int dimx){
int i;

fs=fopen (s,"r");
for (i=0;i<dimy;i++)
        fgets(sopa->matrix[i],dimx,fs);
        limpabn(sopa->matrix[i]);
}

//Clears \n at the end of a string
void limpabn (char *s){
int i;
for (i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++); if (s[i]=='\n') s[i]='\0';
}
```

My main looks like this. I'm opening the file and printing the matrix:

```
int main(){
struct dicionario sopa;
DICIONARIO y=&sopa;

int dimy=3, dimx=4;
FILE *fs;

abresopa(fs,"soup.txt",y,dimy,dimx);

for (i=0;i<dimy;i++) printf("%s",y->matrix[i]);

return 0;}
```

I was hoping to print this:

```
ORCARAIOATNS
```

But i got this instead

```
ORCA
RAI
```

What am i doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: `for (i=0;s[i]!='\n';i++); if (s[i]=='\n') s[i]='\0';`

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?" - you are trying to use the language without having learnt it first.

Comment: Hey @vidit, that is to go to the \n at the end of a word and replace it with a \0. It was working when i created it...

Comment: @PedroLino That's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: The body of the `for` loop in `abresopa` is indented -- but that is not how C works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<dimy;i++)
        fgets(sopa->matrix[i],dimx,fs);//<-- dimx is small size for read (XXXX\n\0)
        limpabn(sopa->matrix[i]);//<- outside for-loop
```

shoud be

```
for (i=0;i<dimy;i++){
    fgets(sopa->matrix[i],dimx+2,fs);
    limpabn(sopa->matrix[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yeap, that was a noob move xD Let me see if it prints what it's suposed to

Comment: Meh, it's not the problem... if my dimX is +2 it works... but if i want to only have half the matrix it messes it up again

Comment: @PedroLino ; My understanding is if the correct, change to `dimX/2 + 1` and `limpabn` must be modified to work even when there is no newline.

Comment: not dimx/2+1. Only dimx+2. If i call abresopa(fs,"soup.txt",y,dimy,dimx+2); the matrix comes out perfecly. But only when i look for the size that's in the file. If my dimx=dimy=2, then i would have a problem instead of the matrix OR-RA

Comment: @PedroLino It seems like there is no problem in `dimx +2` matrix data to read if a 2x2. I do not understand well your problem maybe.

Comment: If i have a matrix ABC DEF and i load dimy=2 and dimx=3+2 then this loads ok. But if i only want to load AB DE and i put dimy=dimx=2, the matrix that is loaded is ABCD and not AB DE.

Comment: @PedroLino ; ah, I think it is good to limit the length in `limpabn` because of the impact to read the next time you try to read in the limit of `fgets`.

Comment: `fgets(sopa->matrix[i],sizeof(sopa->matrix[i]),fs);sopa->matrix[i][dimx]='\0';`

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is used like this:

```
char line[256];
fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
if (p) *p = '\0';
```

Comment: how do i store it in my struct like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working instance. Note that array widths are just as an example. It's not very difficult to load the result a matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void strip(char *s)
{
    char *p2 = s;
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        if (*s != '\n')
        {
            *p2++ = *s++;
        }
        else
        {
            ++s;
        }
    }
    *p2 = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char mx[1024];
    char line[200];
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 200, f))
    {
        strip(line);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            strcpy(mx, line);
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(mx, line);
        }
        i++;

    }
    printf("%s\n", mx);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very odd. Why is it removing tabs from anywhere in the string? Normally a `strip` function removes whitespace (including spaces) only from the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: After your edit all it's really doing is removing the newline. A good way to do that is demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Well it is what it is, I guess you comment manes sense - btw I am intentionally only removing the newline. Your way is better, didn't think of it but I guess I now know a little bit more about properly doing things then a couple of hours ago :)